# server-side javascript - classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, javascript

In client-side javascript the "this" operator is the window object.
What is the "this" operator in classic asp server-side javascript?

In the following code, what is “this” referencing when run in classic ASP server-side ?

```
test();

function test()
{
    Response.Write(typeof(this));
}
```

Comment: The `this` operator is only `window` if the function it appears within is called in the context of `window` (e.g. `window.myFunction()`), which it is by default if you don't provide a context. I've never seen a use for this in any well written program. `this` becomes useful when you call a function in the context of an actual object such as `someButton.focus()` (where `this` is equal to `someButton` inside the focus function)

Comment: A better question might be "what is the global scope object in asp server-side javascript?" I think that is what you want to know.

Comment: @David @Gabe he means server side JScript used to write classic ASP, it's not related to client side JavaScript at all except the basic syntax..

Comment: I think one way to find out what's in global scope would be to write a simple asp script that has `for(var prop in this) Response.Write(prop);`. Doing something similar on a Windows Script Host JScript file on the desktop just gave me 3 properties: `WSH`, `WScript` and `prop`

Comment: Yes I want to know what the global object is. I don't think "for(var prop in this) Response.Write(prop);" works in classic asp

Answer (score 2):

The `this` object seems to receive special treatment in the global scope of a server-side asp page. In my tests, you can append `this.` to global objects like `Response` (as Shadow Wizard suspected):

```
this.Response.write("foo!");
```

Works fine. But you cannot reflect on the `this` object itself. Trying `for(var key in this)` threw an exception:

> An unhandled exception ('Object doesn't support this action') occurred in w3wp.exe [5868].

You get the same exception just for testing the existence of `this`:

```
if (this) { ... }
```

So it is not a normal javascript object at all, and (as Shadow Wizard says) is pretty useless in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

You mean server side JScript, not JavaScript.

In JScript you don't have any window or "global object" like in client side JavaScript so "this" is pretty much meaningless unless you're inside object or class, then `this` refers to the instance of that object.

The [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w062xezx%28VS.85%29.aspx) explains it pretty well.

Comment: does "meaningless" mean `undefined`? `null`? an object with no properties?

Comment: @Gabe - I don't have classic ASP environment here to confirm it, but I believe it won't be null or undefined e.g. probably `this.Response.Write("hello");` will work.

Comment: jscript and javascript on the server-side asp is the same thing. <script language="javascript" runat="server"> and <script language="jscript" runat="server"> both work. The global "this" object is not null or undefined as the following code displays "object":      test();
function test() { Response.Write(typeof(this)); }

Answer (score 1):

The global scope object in Classic ASP JScript is [IScriptingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524971.aspx) from [asptlb.h](http://vdfwinapi.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Include/Asptlb.h). In Classic ASP, this object is not enumerable. The only objects defined on IScriptingContext are:

```
<%@ Language="Javascript"%>

<%
Response.Write(typeof this.Application + "<br>");
Response.Write(typeof this.Request + "<br>");
Response.Write(typeof this.Response + "<br>");
Response.Write(typeof this.Server + "<br>");
Response.Write(typeof this.Session + "<br>");

Response.Write(Object.prototype.toString.call(this) + "<br>");
%>
```

which prints:

```
object
object
object
object
object
[object Object]
```

Comment: This sounds like the right answer, but... where'd you get that information?  Where does it state in the classic ASP doc that "the global scope object is an IScriptingContext" ?    I believe you, but I would like to see the source of that information.

Answer (score 0):

`this` doesn't always point to `window`.

What is `this` in the following code?

```
function Test() {
    var obj = {};
    obj.newFunc = function() { this.value = 42; }
    obj.newFunc(); // "this" is "obj"
    var obj2 = new obj.newFunc(); // Whoa, what's going on? "this" is the new object
}
```

In client-side JS and server-side JS, `this` only points to the context object in which a function has been called.

Comment: "What is this in the following code?" — nothing because it appears only in a method that never gets called ;)