# Equivalent to window in JScript Runtime

Tags: jscript, wsh

In a normal browser javascript environment, you always have the global `window` object to fall back on but is there a default accessible global object for the Microsoft JScript Runtime or at least a way to check for one?

Comment: [A related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402057/server-side-javascript-classic-asp), albeit about Classic ASP, not WSH.

Comment: There is more general solution for global context object - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9107491/987850

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/52f50e9t%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), there is a `Global` object, however a quick test reveals that it is not directly accessible:

```
WScript.Echo(Global.escape('hello world')); // Error: 'Global' is undefined
```

What you can do, however, is take advantage of the fact that `this` in a global context refers to the global object and save the reference to a variable:

```
var __global__ = this;
WScript.Echo(__global__.escape('hello world')); // happy times
```

Comment: Two for two. I owe you a beer.